# combining initial Razor output with Angular updates

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have ASP.NET5 / MVC6 application. The user loads the page and Razor View is responsible for the output of the data. For example (it is a made-up example, for illustration only):

```
<div>@Model.Quantity</div>
```

The user has ability to update quantity, which is done through POST from Angular $resource service. HttpPost on the server updates the database, and returns new quantity in JSON format. I want to update the value on the page without refreshing the whole page. It is clear how to do it in JQuery:

```
$("#quantity").html(data)
```

But I would like to stay with Angular, if possible. So, I imagine something like that:

```
<div ng-controller="inventoryCtrl as vm">

<script>
vm.Model.Quantity = @Model.Quantity
</script>

<div>{{vm.Model.Quantity}}</div>
</div>
```

and then callback function in the controller would update `Model.Quantity`

But this doesn't work... vm is undefined.

There must be a better way!

Comment: I know its bad to use `ng-init`, but just give a try `<div ng-controller="inventoryCtrl as vm" ng-init="vm.Model.Quantity = @Model.Quantity">`

Comment: There are about 50 elements; some of them complex objects. If I could do something like `ng-init="vm.Model = @Model`, I would do that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But this doesn't work... vm is undefined.

You need to capture `this`:

```
var that = this;
```

so that inside the `then` callback of the AJAX request on your resource you could update the model:

```
.then(function(result) {
    that.Model.Quantity = result;
});
```

---

UPDATE:

I misunderstood your question. It seems that you have problems with the initial rendering. This can be easily achieved like that:

```
<script>
    var quantity = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Quantity));
    // declare the quantity that came from the server as constant value
    app.constant('quantity', quantity);
</script>
```

which can be injected into your controller:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function (quantity) {
    this.Model.Quantity = quantity;
});
```

---

UPDATE:

You could store your entire object graph into a constant as well:

```
<script>
    var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
    app.constant('model', model);
</script>
```

Comment: I don't have a problem during the AJAX request. The problem is in the initial rendering of the page. I want to avoid displaying just the markup, and then go back to the server for data. In other words, I want to render all data from the server, yet to be able to update specific values later.

Comment: I have updated my answer to illustrate how you could register a constant value and then inject it into your Angular controller.

Comment: I understand your suggestion. If I had a few simple (scalar) variable in the model, this would be great approach. But my model is quite complex. To stay with quantity example, I may have a table of orders for a customer, and the user can change the customer, and new orders would load. Again, I have no problems loading them purely through Angular (load empty markup, and then load data separately); or change DOM with JQuery during AJAX callbacks. But getting everything into constants doesn't look feasible. Does it?

Comment: There's nothing preventing you from storing an entire object graph into a constant. It's as simple as: `var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));`. And then define your constant: `app.constant('model', model);`. I have also updated my answer to illustrate that.

Comment: you suggested `Json.Encode()`, however, Razor complains that there is no such method (although I see this example in numerous places). Instead, I am using `Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject()`. Do you have an opinion as to why Encode() throws an error, and if it is the same to use SerializeObject. I realize it deserves a separate question - but it is a minor (and not that important) clarification of your excellent suggestion - so I hope, you don't mind!

Comment: That should be the same. I suppose `Json.Encode` was removed in MVC6.